# Full screen intent remote notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am developing a WebRTC call application, when user A call user B the sever send a notification to user B via FCM

How can I create a full screen intent remote notifications in server via FCM? it is possible? Is there alternative way?

Comment: What was the solution, were you able to solve this?
I'm building a ride hailing app. What do you prefer the captain app  should do when receiving a new request? Should I go with full screen intent notification? or should I use something like system_alert_window

Comment: Has anyone solved this?